# Assign "No data" to some pixel values

Tags: grass-gis

I have a GeoTIFF Float32 raster DEM with some pixels with value -9999. How can I assign "No data" to those pixels using GRASS 7.4?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

> r.mapcalc “output_raster = if(input_raster<-1000, null(),
>   input_raster)”